# How to best find the minimum positive difference of a value compared to a table efficiently using one Excell cell only?

Tags: excel

I want to avoid VBA as much as possible and try to find a solution in a single cell--if possible. I have been trying to find a way to do so, but I have no idea how to.

The logic is summarized in the image below. In words, the conditions are:

1. `Search Name` is looked for in the `Name` column of the right table.
2. `Search Date` has to be greater than the `Date` in the right table.
3. `Search Date` minus `Date` has to be the positive minimum value.
4. Return the `Pay` that matches the criteria--which is 500 in the example.

[image]

Comment: the third condition is a bit weird and hard to do with formulas. Can you rephrase it perhaps? Any formula will always take into consideration ALL values in the column. Your screenshot highlights the path to the found value, but the 3rd condition is seen in the context of the first condition (i.e. Name = John), whereas a formula will compare all values in the column, so the minimum positive value will include rows for Michael as well and the whole thing falls over. Can the month of the Search Date perhaps be used to limit the found date?

Comment: @teylyn I am not quite sure if I understand, but what I got was that the 3rd condition, in formula form, will not care about the first condition and still include Michael's figures? I believe if the formula is created in a nested loop kind of way, it should be accounted. As for the search date only limited to the months, it can be dangerous due to possible several changes in a month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following array formula (i.e. you need to enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, if you are successful, you will see the braces appear in the formula bar):

```
=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(A2,IF(F:F=B2,E:E)))
```

[image]

The formula will return `#N/A` if there are no dates earlier than the Search Date.

**NOTE:** The dates have to be sorted in ascending order for this to work

---

**EDIT:** A little more robust that doesn't require sorting:

```
=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(MAX(IF((F:F=B2)*(E:E<A2),E:E)-A2),IF((F:F=B2)*(E:E<A2),E:E)-A2,0))
```

[image]

**Note:** Since this doesn't use `MATCH`, you won't get `#N/A` in case there are no dates earlier than the Search Date and you will instead get `Pay` (i.e. the header). If you want to get *something else*, then you can wrap the whole function in an `IFERROR`, relying on the fact that excel returns an error if one attempts to multiply a text with a number, something like this:

```
=IFERROR(Formula*1, "No pay matched")
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken `Match`, returns the first instance found in the table which is greater than or equal `A2`--which is why sorting in ascending order is needed? If true, the problem for the application would be that it's not too flexible and might lead to errors. It's going to be used in a huge application so something more robust is preferred. Is there a way to prevent the need to sort the dates?

Comment: @Pherdindy That's correct (for the non-exact matching of `MATCH` anyway). I have added an alternative that would not require sorting (I just left the table sorted in the screen capture). Hm I forgot to mention that if there are two rows with the same name and date, then the first pay will be the result. That should not be a problem, right? Since I do expect to have unique rows for date and name together.

Comment: Thanks this is great. Never knew how much array formulas can do this much will have to read on them. Right I cannot think of any instances where 2 rows will have the same name and date.

Comment: Using whole column references for array formulas is a really, really bad idea, because each whole column reference will consist of over a million rows and with many of these, the performance of the spreadsheet will take a hit. Better to ringfence  the ranges to only the rows that contain data.

Comment: Yes, the smaller the dataset, the faster it will be. It's not too hard fortunately to edit the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with SumProduct, which does not require Ctrl-Shift-Enter

```
=SUMPRODUCT($G$2:$G$9,(A2>$E$2:$E$9)*(MONTH(A2)=MONTH($E$2:$E$9)*($F$2:$F$9=B2)))
```

The logic commands that the Search Date is in the same month as the Date column.

If you have the new Dynamic Array functions, that are currently in preview in the Insider Fast build of Excel 365, you can use

```
=FILTER($G$2:$G$9,(A2>$E$2:$E$9)*(MONTH(A2)=MONTH($E$2:$E$9)*($F$2:$F$9=B2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I will actually try out both to see how they perform and in terms of speed. Problems with my spreadsheets has always been the speed. Will send updates

Comment: I think your formula will break when there are 2 dates in the same month less than the `Search date`. Isn't it?

Comment: I agree that the data sample provided does not cater for many scenarios. So, to remove all ambiguity, a more detailed data sample would be helpful.

Comment: @teylrn Basically, it is a payroll system think of the search date and search name as individual entries to be matched to the employee's details regarding their pay. To be safe, best to assume there can be several changes in a month since it is unpredictable. The actual data might not also consider the special cases and might add complexity to the question so I created a simpler one